# Is there a way to have the hunchentoot:*dispatch-table* update automatically on function redefinition?

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I have set up the dispatch-table in the following-manner:

```lisp
(setq hunchentoot:*dispatch-table*
        (mapcar #'(lambda (regex-and-handler)
                    (hunchentoot:create-regex-dispatcher (first regex-and-handler)
                                                         (second regex-and-handler)))
                (list (list "^/one$" #'page-one)
                      (list "^/two$" #'page-two))))
```

Now, if I redefine the function `page-one`, the `*dispatch-table*` still uses the old definition, and uses the new definition only when the `(setq ...)` form is re-evaluated. Is there a way to get it to pick up the new function definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function's names, as a symbol, instead of resolving the symbol to a function object with `function` (reader syntax `#'`) when evaluating the list. In other words:

```
....
(list (list "^/one$" 'page-one)
      (list "^/two$" 'page-two))))
```

Comment: Wonder why didn't I think of that! Ah, alright, I got some other error, which I mistook for this error. Anyways, thanks!